# How to access microsoft access database (1997) in java

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, jdbc

I try to connect and use microsoft access database 1997 in java with driver : sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver

You can find below the code used :

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
String database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:\\ft120.mdb";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "", "");
```

When I run this, I have this exception :

```
 java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][Pilote ODBC Microsoft Access] Impossible d'ouvrir une base de données créée avec une version antérieure de votre application.
```

I use JDK 1.7.

Can you help me? What driver should I use to access Microsoft Access Database 1997?

Thank you.

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/

Comment: For what it's worth I am unable to recreate the issue. I just opened an Access97 `.mdb` file and retrieved data from its table using the same ODBC driver that you are trying to use (32-bit Jet ODBC). If you care to upload a copy of the `.mdb` file to a site like [wikisend.com](http://wikisend.com) and post a link to the file here then we can try to assist, otherwise you may simply have to upgrade the `.mdb` file to a newer format that your system can read.

Answer (score 1):

Next time it will be very kind of you to translate into English all non-English but valuable sentences.

For example Google-translated error message means "Can not open a database created with a previous version of your application".

So it seems that the answer is that you are probably using wrong driver version that is newer than you `mdb` file.

I think that you have 2 directions

1. try to find compatibe driver
2. open mdb file with newer Access and export the data to newer format. Probably after that it will be easier to find compatible java driver.

Good luck.